# Identify an incoming file through NetworkStream C#

Tags: c#, ftp, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am making a client/server chat application using TcpClient and TcpListener classes. It should be able to transfer text messages and files between client and server. I am able to handle text messages by making a thread for each separate client and then making a secondary thread for receiving incoming message making primary thread reserved for sending messages. Now if I would be able to identify that incoming message is a file and not a text message then I know how to handle it using NetworkStream and FileStream. But I am unable to do so. Code to handle incoming file is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32633/Sending-Files-using-TCP?msg=4566917#xx4566917xx). Also please tell me if there are any limitations using NetworkStream for FTP.

Comment: Sounds like you should put the message type in the protocol, basically... have a header for each message specifying the message length (in bytes - not in characters for text messages) and type.

Comment: I do not know how to specify message type. Is there any overload of NetworkStream.Read and NetworkStream.Write that could do that? Actually I am new to networking, Please help me figure it out. @JonSkeet

Comment: No, you have to design the protocol to include this information. This isn't specific to network streams or to .NET - it's a matter of designing the format of the data.

Comment: ok I got it. it is like I have to append some marker that would tell the receiver method that it is a file. right?

Comment: Well, I would *prepend* it rather than appending it - and have a marker either way, ideally saying how long the message is, so you know how much to read before the next marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: Build your own protocol.

By building your own good communication protocol you can control all data/message flow.

For example;
1-User wants to send a file to server
2-Client sends a command to inform the server that it will send a file.Like ;
`@File@filename;filesize;`
3-Server sends a ready message back to client `@FileAccepted@`
4-Server begins to listen buffer packages and when it receives writes them to an stream.
5-When client receives `{@FileAccepted@}` command begins to send packages to server. Be sure their buffer sizes are same.
6-When all bytes complete client sends `@FileEnd@` in diffrent buffer (i use 256 for commands and 1024 for file transfer)
7-When server receives 256 byte command looks if its the `@FileEnd@` command and is true flushes file stream and closes connection.

I recomment you use Async

Listen for connections on server like this

```
server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServerAcceptEnd,server);
```

And when a connection is present

```
public void ServerAcceptEnd(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if(!ar.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Something went wrong
        AcceptServer();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        var cli = servertc.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        if(cli.Connected)
        {
            //Get the first Command   
            cli.GetStream().BeginRead(serverredbuffer,0,serverredbuffer.Length,ServerFirstReadEnd,cli);
        }
        else
        {
            //Connection was not successfull log and wait
            AcceptServer();
        }
    }
    catch(Exceiption ex)
    {
        //An error occur log and wait for new connections
        AcceptServer();
    }
 }
```

When first command received ;

```
    public void ServerFirstReadEnd(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
    if(!ar.IsCompleted)
    {
        //Something went wrong
        AcceptServer();
        return;
    }
        try
        {
            TcpClient cli = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState;
            int read = cli.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
            string req = toString(serverredbuffer);  
            if(req.StartsWith("@File@"))
            {
                //File Received
                string filename = req.Replace("@File@","");
                string[] spp = filename.Split(';');
                filename = spp[0];
                serverreceivetotalbytes = Convert.ToInt64(spp[1]);
                cli.GetStream().Write(toByte("@FileAccepted@",256),0,256);
                cli.GetStream().BeginRead(serverreceivebuffer,0,1024,ServerReadFileCyle,cli)   
            }
            else
            {
                //Message Received
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //An error occur log and wait for new connections
            AcceptServer();
        }
    }
```

File receive method ;

```
    public void ServerReadFileCyle(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        TcpClient cli = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState;
        if(ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            int read = cli.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
            if(read == 256)
            {
                try
                {
                    string res = toString(serverreceivebuffer);
                    if(res == "@FileEnd@")
                        read = 0;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            if(read > 0)
            {
                serverfile.Write(serverreceivebuffer,0,read);
                cli.GetStream().BeginRead(serverreceivebuffer,0,1024,ServerReadFileCyle,cli);
            }
            else
            {
                serverfile.Flush();
                serverfile.Dispose();
                AcceptServer();
            }
        }
    }
```

This part was server side.And for client side;

When sending a file first send a information to server for file and then wait for a response from server.

```
try
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
    ofd.FileName="";
    if(ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filesendpath = ofd.FileName;
        senderfilestream = System.IO.File.Open(filesendpath,System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        sendertotalbytes = senderfilestream.Length;
        filesendcommand = "@File@" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filesendpath) + ";" + senderfilestream.Length;
        senderfilestream.Position = 0;
        sendertc.BeginConnect(ip.Address,55502,FileConnect,null);
    }
    else
    {
        //No file selected
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Error connecting log the error
}
```

If connection is successfull , then send the file command and wait for response ;

```
    public void FileConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if(ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            sender.EndConnect(ar);
            if(sender.Connected)
            {
                sender.GetStream().Write(toByte(filesendcommand,256),0,256);
                sender.GetStream().BeginRead(ComputerNameBuffer,0,256,FileSendCyleStarter,null);

            }
        }
    }
```

When response received look if it is successfull an accepted;

```
    public void FileSendCyleStarter(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if(ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            if(sender.Connected)
            {
                string kabul = toString(ComputerNameBuffer);
                if(kabul == "@FileAccepted@")
                {
                    senderfilestream.BeginRead(filesendbuffer,0,1024,FileSendCyle,null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sending a file has three steps;
1-Read a chunk for a start
2-Then send the chunk to server.if its completed send @FileEnd@ command and skip step 3
3-Read next chunk of file
4-Return step 2 if file isnt completed

Step 1 :

```
senderfilestream.BeginRead(filesendbuffer,0,1024,FileSendCyle,null);
```

Step 2-4 :

```
    public void FileSendCyle(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if(ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            if(sendertc.Connected)
            {
                int  read = senderfilestream.EndRead(ar);
                if(read > 0)
                {
                    sendertc.GetStream().BeginWrite(filesendbuffer,0,read,FileSendCyle2,null);

                }
                else
                {

                    sendertc.GetStream().Write(toByte("@FileEnd@",256),0,256);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 3 :

```
    public void FileSendCyle2(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if(ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            if(sendertc.Connected)
            {
               sendertc.GetStream().EndWrite(ar);
               senderfilestream.BeginRead(filesendbuffer,0,1024,FileSendCyle,null);
            }
        }
    }
```

In abowe example there are two methods called toString() and toByte().I used them for converting strings to bytes and bytes to strings.Here are them ;

```
    public string toString(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0","");
    }
    public byte[] toByte(string str,int bufferlenght)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str,0,str.Length,buffer,0);
        return buffer;
    }
```

The code abowe example isn't perfect and need lots of error handling and flow controls.I write theese to give you an idea and a jump start.

Hope any part of it helps anybody ^_^